# How can I access a running thread

Tags: python, global-namespace

By starting the main, I´m starting a thread that keeps a connection to a opcua server alive (and a few things more).
I now want to open a function inside this thread but I don´t want to import everything again (because it takes to long).

In **if __name__ == "__main__":** 
it is working, but when I run a second script **goIntoThread.py**, it is not working. Obviously because I didn´t import the modules...

What are my options to trigger e.g. thd.doSomethingInThread() without importing everything again?

Thnaks alot!

main.py

```py
import time

def importOnlyMain():
    global KeepConnected
    from keepConnected import KeepConnected

if __name__ == "__main__":
    importOnlyMain()
    global thd
    thd = KeepConnected()
    thd.start()
    time.sleep(3)
    thd.doSomethingInThread()

def goIntoThread():
    print("Going to Thread")
    thd.doSomethingInThread()
```

goIntoThread.py

```py
import main

main.goIntoThread()
```

> **Copy Comment**: I get the following error:
>
> ```
> thd.setBool() 
> NameError: global name 'thd' is not defined
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "start goIntoThread.py" ?

Comment: I want to run a second script called goIntoThread.py.

Comment: How do you run it? `python goIntoThread.py`? If that's the case then it is not a different thread

Comment: But it´s not working. I get the following error:     thd.setBool()
NameError: global name 'thd' is not defined

Comment: I cannot see any `setBool()` in your code, could you show us the whole code?